# Windows Subsystem for Linux - How to change the default user

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I'm using/calling my bash from VSCode, and multiple other places, and I don't want it to boot to root whenever bash is opened. Is there a way that you can set the default user (say User 1) that is booted into whenever bash is opened?

Comment: Sure, you need to set a password for the root account (which effectively will allow you to set up WSL as any normal linux distro). (e.g. just call `passwd`) Then you can use `useradd` to add your user (if you use your default windows login name -- it will be used by default on WSL start). That should do it. Your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/).